# How to make reactstrap modal draggable?

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, reactstrap

how to make **reactstrap** modal draggable? I have tried by using **react-draggable** plugin but it is not working properly. It is work only inner section of whole modal. My code is given below.

if i use **< Draggable >** component into inner section of **< Modal >** tag then it is worked and move header text as well as body text. it should be worked for whole modal if anybody there please help me.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter } from "reactstrap";
import Draggable from "react-draggable";

class DraggableModal extends Component {
 render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <Draggable>
        <Modal
          isOpen={this.state.showModal}
          toggle={() => {
            this.setState({ showModal: false });
            this.props.modalClose();
          }}
        >
          <ModalHeader
            className="modal-header bg-primary modal-title text-white"
            toggle={() => {
              this.setState({ showModal: false });
              this.props.modalClose();
            }}
          >
            Test Header
          </ModalHeader>
          {this.state.loading ? <Spinner /> : ""}
          <ModalBody
            style={{
              height: modalSettings.modalBodyHeight + "px"
            }}
          >
            <div
              className="form-group row"             
            >
              <div className="formRow col-sm-12">{this.renderData()}</div>
            </div>
          </ModalBody>
        </Modal>
        </Draggable>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

}

Comment: I don't see any issue here. Can you create a codepen?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dswb4y

here you can see, header and body can be moved

Comment: Hi Pritam, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found some issue's in your given [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dswb4y).

You have wrapped `Modal`, `ModalHeader` & `ModalBody` with `Draggable` separately.

Wrapping `ModalHeader` & `ModalBody` with `Draggable` is of no use and will only create weired behaviour. You need to remove it.

You probably obly need to wrap your `Modal` with `Draggable`.

---

Your `Modal` is not getting dragged because of the `transform` property,

```
.modal-dialog {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
    min-width: 500px !important;
}
```

Here you have applied `!important`.

The `Draggable` internally work with `transform` property only. When you wrap any element with `Draggable`, it will apply this `CSS`,

```
touch-action: none;
transform: translate(0px, 0px);
```

And on the basis of drag / cursor position it will update the `transform` property. As you have alreay applied `!important` on `transform` property, this update will have no effect and in result your `Modal` will not get dragged.

**So, by removing `CSS` of `modal-dialog` your code will work.**

---

Another suggestion is you have written custom `CSS` for your `Modal`.

You need to add `bootstrap` in your project **(reactstrap takes CSS from bootstrap only)**, which will provide `CSS` for `Modal` so that you don't need to write custom `CSS`.

```
npm i bootstrap --save
```

And you can add `bootstrap.min.css` in `index.js` file like,

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yznkmu)

**Note:** If you want your `Modal` at center of screen, for that you can add custom `CSS`.

Comment: thank you for explaining the issue. 

position:fixed was not the actual reason and also not the custom css. 
Issue was  "transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;" and "position:absolute" css. After commenting out "transform" property and replace the 'absolute' position with 'fixed', the 'dragging' is working.

Comment: @PritamJyotiRay, Yes your analysis are correct. I have also did some analysis on how `Draggable` works and updated my answer based on your comment for future use.

Comment: draggable component is prevented to take input on input field or text-area field, do you have any idea on it?

Answer (score 1):

**The simplest solution ever**

You just need to **wrap** your `Modal` code with `Draggable`

**Steps of the solution**:

1. Install `react-draggable` package using NPM

```sh
npm i react-draggable
```

2. import `react-draggable` to your component:

```js
import Draggable from 'react-draggable';
```

3. Wrap you `reacstrap` modal with this `Draggable`:

```js
<Draggable>
  <Modal
    isOpen={this.props.isModalOpen}
    toggle={this.props.toggleModal}
    className="gray-header-modal md"
  >
    <ModalHeader>
      <label className="modal-header-title text-dark">Modal Title</label>
      <img
        src="/images/close.png"
        alt="close"
        width="20px"
        className="closeIcon"
        onClick={this.props.toggleModal}
      />
    </ModalHeader>
    <ModalBody>
      <Row>
        <Col>
          // Modal body
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </ModalBody>
  </Modal>
</Draggable>
```

Comment: I have tried the same manner but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is better and very simple, because you can draggable the modal only with the header and so also text marking inside the modal is possible.

The `handle` class name specifies a selector to be used as the handle that initiates drag.

```
import { Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody } from "reactstrap";
import Draggable from "react-draggable";

...

<Draggable handle=".handle">
  <Modal size="lg" toggle={function noRefCheck(){}}>
    <ModalHeader toggle={function noRefCheck(){}} className="handle">
      Modal Title
    </ModalHeader>
    <ModalBody>
      Modal Body
    </ModalBody>
  </Modal>
</Draggable>
```